# Multiple permission protection level

Tags: android

If a permission has the following protection level

```
 "signature|privileged|development|appop"
```

How is it decided if your app recieves this permission?
What does appop level mean?

Comment: The vertical pipe operator (`|`) means "or". `signature` means that your APK is signed by the same signing key as signed whatever is being defended by the permission. `privileged` (formerly `system`) means that your app is installed on the system partition. I am hazy on the precise definition of the other two.

Comment: privileged means specifically in the system/priv-app/ partition.